# Are geohash tiles the same size anywhere on the globe?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, gis, latitude-longitude, geohashing

I'm trying to use geohashes to group points from all over the US into "tiles". I'm using geohash 7, but I can't wrap my head around how a geohash "tile" in the north of the US would be the same size of one in the south due to the distortion of the globe. My question really is: can I assume that the size of a geohash 7 tile in the north of the US is the same size as one in the south?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of geotiles varies with latitude because the tiles are drawn on top of a rectangular projection of a sphere and there is no way to make such a projection without introducing significant distortion.

[image: Geohash tile sizes]

The most common projection tech folks run into is [web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection). [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix) shows us that this projection is *not* equal area:

[image: Tissot's indicatrix for mercator]

If you need equal area tiles for, eg, statistical purposes packages such as my [dggridR](https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR) provide this functionality by tiling a spherical representation of the Earth with hexagons, thereby inducing less distortion.

[image: dggridR hexagonal tiles]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is absolutely perfect!